# error " Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' "?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an error:

> Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

I'm trying to add event listener and get value from element. Everything works fine  but this error shows up in console .

```js
public componentDidMount() {
  const element = document.querySelector(".mdc-list")
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    this.data.menu.title = e.target.innerText
  })
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't. `Window` is possible `EventTarget` and it doesn't have `innerText`.  Also `Document`. You need to check which `EventTarget` was it.

Comment: What `console.log(e.target.nodeName)` outputs?

Comment: works fine for me, but depends on what type of element was clicked: https://jsfiddle.net/bt0mozp3/2/

Comment: Try `this.data.menu.title = e.target.value`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is a TypeScript issue, cast the event.target to it’ type to tell TypeScript that it has the property you set for it.

```
const input = event.target as HTMLElement;
this.data.menu.title=input.innerText
```

Comment: for someone see this error in html template like me:  $any($event.target).innerText

Answer (score 1):

You can either make a type guard to narrow down the event target type.

Or just cast the event target to whichever element you're getting as a target:

`this.data.menu.title = <HTMLInputElement>(e.target).innerText;`