# Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

I'm using Typescript for Puppeteer. I'm trying to get innerText from an element.

```
const data = await page.$eval(selector, node => node.innerText);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'

I tried casting to HTMLElement like described in this question:
[error " Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886637/error-property-innertext-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget)

```
const data = await page.$eval(selector, <HTMLElement>(node: HTMLElement) => node.innerText);
```

As well as creating my own Interface like this:

```
interface TextElement extends Element {
    innerText: string;
}
```

But in each case I'm getting the error that innerText does not exist on this particular type.

> Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Why is this happening and how to deal with this?

Comment: Have you considered using the more standard `textContent` instead?

Comment: Why don't you try this - ```await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("your_selector").innerText)``` Before trying execute in console this ```document.querySelector("your_selector").innerText``` to check whether you're getting the required result.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - You're right that textContent seems to work. However I actually really need the additional features of innerText. But I wonder why it won't work even on my own Interface?

Comment: @PySaad this throws the same error.

Comment: `innerText` may sometimes be preferable to `textContent` if there are child elements and whitespace in the mix. http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

```js
const data = await page.$eval(selector, node => (node as HTMLElement).innerText);
```

or:

```js
const data = await page.$eval(selector, node => (<HTMLElement>node).innerText);
```

*UPDATE:*

So, after some exchange on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32972), it's clear why the syntax from this question does not work. It actually defines anonymous generic function.

```js
<HTMLElement>(node: HTMLElement) => node.innerText
```

Clearer example would be following:

```js
function myFunction<T>(node: T) {
    node.innerText; // Property 'innerText' does not exist on 'T'
}

const data = await page.$eval(selector, myFunction);
```

Unfortunate naming of `T` as `HTMLElement` creates confusion.

Comment: You're right. It works. Thank you. Care to explain why my solutions did not work?

Comment: This answer should get more votes!

Answer (score 7):

For those who needs to fix this error for any element returned from `querySelector`:

```js
const el = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('#app');

if (el) {
  el.innerText = content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the next syntax:

```js
const title = (document.querySelector(".someselector") as HTMLHeadingElement)?.innerText;
```

I had to specify the element of the issue. For the question it might be better to use something different than HTMLElement